# Wordpress and zend directories

Tags: wordpress, apache, zend-framework, routes

I just want to make a site. Because i need the customer to enter data into the site i have used wordpress ( a simple CMS ). This can help me with SEO too.

The problem that i have right now is that for larger data, i have made another application in Zend Framework, that runs much faster and is very custom. My usual user must not see that i have used two different platforms, so the passing from one route to another must be done from both of the sites.

I must use only the domain.( i don't want to create a subdomain, or different folder ).

I have tried to make one file, that roots both applications, but is not very dynamic. I must hardcode the routes of the Zend platform.

I have tried to modify from apache server, but is not very dynamic too.

What i want to have:

The wordpress to be on : www.domain.com ( because of the CMS ). And if i have routes on the Zend Platform like : "DesignController", to go to: www.domain.com/design. 
For sure i won't have the same routes on both sites.

Thanks.